# How to use Arangodb Fuzzy search using AQL

Tags: go, arangodb

I want to use fuzzy search of ArangoDB. So i created a View linked with 3 collection. Now i am trying below query:

```
FOR doc IN SEARCH_VIEW SEARCH ANALYZER(LIKE(doc.fullName, @fullName), 'text_en') OR ANALYZER(LIKE(doc.filePath, @pageTitle), 'text_en') RETURN {fullName:doc.fullName, pageTitle:doc.pageTitle}
```

Assuming i have few full names exist as below:

system
administrator
john wick

and if i pass params as below:

"stm" or "admnsta"

I am expecting result as below:

system
administrator

But the query gives empty.

Answer (score 0):

If the attribute value contains the given string in your query `@fullName` and `@pageTitle` should contains a wildcard operator:

- _: A single arbitrary character
- %: Zero, one or many arbitrary characters

i.e. passing `%minis%` will match `administrator`

If the string you provide is not contained in the attribute value then you should check the [LEVENSHTEIN_MATCH](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/functions-arangosearch.html#levenshtein_match) function.